# How to generate a module with a routing module in an Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, command-line-interface

I have a new Ionic project and am trying to create a new feature folder with its routing module. I tried the command provided by the documentation:

```
ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.module
```

on an Ionic project and I have this error:

```
File customers/customers.module.ts does not exist.
```

I couldn't figure out what it is the problem. Maybe smtg in the ionic architecture?

Thanks.

Comment: Just add the `--routing true` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
ng generate module xxx --routing
```

BTW, you can try the help to see options:

```
options:
  --flat
    Create the new files at the top level of the current project root.
  --lint-fix
    Apply lint fixes after generating the module.
  --module (-m)
    The declaring NgModule.
  --project
    The name of the project.
  --route
    The route path for a lazy-loaded module. When supplied, creates a component in the new module, and adds the route to that component in the `Routes` array declared in the module provided in the `--module` option.
  --routing
    Create a routing module.
  --routing-scope
    The scope for the new routing module.
```

Comment: Great thanks, where is the documentation for this?